# C# WinForm: Accessing a certain Control in Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, controls, panel

I have 3 `Controls` inside a `TabPage tabpage1`; let's call them `panel1`, `panel2` and `datagridview1`. I'm trying to make a general method for accessing `panel2`. How do I access this `Panel` in `TabPage.Controls`? I've found out that I can use something like `tabpage1.Controls[1]`. But how do I know the index of `panel2`? And how do I set its index?

Comment: Please provide a information about what you are using: `WinForms`, `WPF`, e.t.c.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria I'm using WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the controls collection.

```
        var ctrls = this.Controls.Find("ControlName", true);
        if (ctrls != null)
           if(ctrls.Length != 0)
               {
                    Control ctrl = ctrls[0];
               }
```

I am not good in C# but I believe it works and you can easy make an universal method from it. (`this` only for the ilustrational purposes - replace with the apriopriate object.

Comment: The thing is, I do not know the Name of the Control because it's a general method. 
I have several tabPages with the same layout, which is why I want to use indices because I can set each panel2 in each tabPage to a certain index.

Comment: You need to know something about the object you look for. Otherwise you will be unable to find it.

Comment: How would knowing the Name of the Control make it a universal method?

Comment: I think that you not really know what you want. Universal method can find all objects having some atributes (like name, type etc), but will never locale the particular one as you need to know something which is distinct

Comment: I believe you somehow add panel2 to your tabPage. So when you are adding your panel2 assign some string to its Name property, and you will be able to find it as PeterJ suggested.

Comment: Because it's a TabPage, I cannot have a use panel2 as Name for every TabPage as there will be conflict. So i cannot simply use this.Controls.Find("panel2", true);

Comment: It does not matter what it is. `this` in my example is only the example. It can be any control you look the child control(s) in.

Comment: You can't have two variables with the same name, but you can add controls to different TabPage's with the same Name property.

Comment: so you will get the collection of the controls.

Comment: `foreach(var ctrl in this.Controls.OfType<_your type_>())
{
  //do something
}`

Comment: If you are working on the designer, then you can't assign the same name, that is right. In this case I recommend using Tag property.